# How to fix modified submodule refs committed on non-master branch?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I unintentionally committed modified submodule refs on my feature branch. I need to reset them to what they are on master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you have to checkout the correct commit SHA in each submodule and then commit those changes in the top-level repo. Here's what I came up with:

1. Merge latest master branch into your branch.
2. Run the following

   ```
   for module in module1 module2 path/to/module3;
   do 
       (cd $module && git checkout "$(git rev-parse origin/master:$module)" && cd -)
   done

   git commit -am 'fix submodule refs' && git push
   ```

#### One Liner

```
for module in module1 module2 path/to/module3; do (cd $module && git checkout "$(git rev-parse origin/master:$module)" && cd -); done; git commit -am 'fix submodule refs' && git push
```

#### Create An Alias

```
alias fix-submodules='for module in module1 module2 path/to/module3; do (cd $module && git checkout "$(git rev-parse origin/master:$module)" && cd -); done; git commit -am "fix submodule refs" && git push'
```

Now You can run: `fix-submodules`

Comment: Rather than ls-tree, cut, etc., you can just run `git rev-parse origin/master:$module` to get the right hash ID.

Comment: I figured there was a better way to get it. Thanks for the tip!